# Create installation file to compile executable file onboard user's computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ubuntu, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an installation file for my PySide6 app for Windows and Ubuntu.

Here is the reason: compiling executable for different system versions requires different system dependencies. (As minimum as Ubuntu version must be compiled with specific version of `ldd` which depend on system version).

But i didn't find too much info about creating installation files for python. Only `pyinstaller` manuals. But, i don't want force users to operate with console.

And additional question (bc i'm pretty sure that dead-end will be here anyway), how can i resolve the `ldd` issue?

Here is the exception after trying to launch pre-built on 23.04 Ubuntu executable on 22.04 Ubuntu:

```
[682115] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIN9bjwo/libpython3.11.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.36' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIN9bjwo/libexpat.so.1)
```

I want to minimise user manipulations while installation process, so that's why i'm looking in installation file way.

Comment: On Linux, you'd probably want an AppImage, Flatpak or Snap to bundle as much of the libraries as possible.